# C# String Splitting of a path to get every sub path

Tags: c#, string, linq

I have this dataset:

- BW\Website Implementation\Phase1\Backlog
- BW\Website Implementation\Phase1\Iteration 0

  ```
  List<string> IterationPaths = new List<string>();
  foreach (WorkItem item in collection)
  {
    List<string> itpath = item.IterationPath.Split('\\').ToList<string>();
    itpath = itpath.Except(IterationPaths).ToList();
    foreach (string path in itpath)
    {
      IterationPaths.Add(path);
    }
  }
  ```

But currently this is giving me:

- BW
- Website Implementation
- Phase1
- Backlog
- Iteration 0

I need it to have:

- BW
- BW\Website Implementation
- BW\Website Implementation\Phase1
- BW\Website Implementation\Phase1\Backlog
- BW\Website Implementation\Phase1\Iteration 0

What tweaks would I have to make for this to work?

Comment: why don't you use the `Path` class? its safer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var itpath = item.IterationPath.Split('\\');

int i = 1;
var result = itpath.Select(x => string.Join("\\", itpath.Take(i++))).ToList();
```

Comment: what about if you're running this on linux?